# A question about the usage of "freeze"

Tags: word-usage, tense

I have a question about "freeze" as in weather conditions.

It is perfectly normal to say:

it rains a lot in Holland

it has been raining a lot lately

it rained last night

if I want to express these conditions with "freeze" are the same constructions possible?

Is it ideomatic to say:

it freezes a lot in Holland

it froze last night

it has been freezing a lot lately?

Comment: I'm not sure what *freeze* means exactly so I don't think it's a good thing to say.  If you said it to me I would ask you to provide more details as to what exactly you were telling me.  Does it get below 0 often?  Does it get icy?  Does it get below -5 often?  If the weather is dry and gets below 0 is that freezing or does it need to be wet and below 0?  In U.S. *freezing* is a general term for *very cold* but it has no quantifiable boundaries.

Comment: I mean "below zero" when water freezes.

Comment: It's not something that is generally discussed in relation to the weather in the U.S.  We are more apt to discuss it being *icy*.  Freezing happens at 32 degrees for us so it's just not as exiting or important.  And the water on a road doesn't really freeze at 0C so no one ever *really* knows when the water starts freezing.  The question is *Is it icy?*

Comment: So how would you express my sentences?

Comment: It's been icy lately.  It's going to get icy tonight. Holland has a lot of icy weather.  Gardeners sometimes need to pay attention to the temperature in order to properly care for their plants.  Our weather services (i.e. government funded organizations) sometimes issue **Frost** or **Hard Freeze** warnings but those are technical descriptions and are quantifiable.

Comment: I suggest Fahrenheit for outdoor temperature.  You should talk to the EU and explain to them why they should switch.

Comment: Or 'We had freezing temperatures last night'. 'We have had a lot of freezing weather lately'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People would understand you but an alternative uses the word *frost*.

> it freezes a lot in Holland

We get a lot of frosts in Holland

> it froze last night

There was a frost last night

> it has been freezing a lot lately?

We have had a lot of frosts lately

In the UK the television weather forecasts usually speak of the danger of overnight frosts rather than overnight freezing. You can also extend this by speaking a a hard frost or a sharp frost in any of the examples above. There are also ground frosts and air frosts but that perhaps strays into technical territory.

Comment: Frost is definitely the better choice.  I will not need to ask what is meant by that.  However, I will associate *Frost* with danger to ground plants and not the formation of ice on roads or sidewalks.  In my experience frost does not necessarily lead to ice.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike *It rained yesterday* or *It snowed yesterday*, it's not very idiomatic to say *It **froze** yesterday* - we nearly always say *It **was freezing** yesterday*.

By the same token, we wouldn't usually say *It freezes a lot in Holland.* Idiomatically, we'd more naturally express that with something like...

> 1: ***It's often freezing in Holland***
> or
> 2: ***They often have [hard] frost[s] in Holland***

Note that ***it's freezing*** usually just means ***it's very cold*** - not necessarily with *specific* relevance to water turning into ice. So the *second* version above is the one the weather forecasters use if they're warning you that the temperature is expected to drop below 0°C (so you might want to protect your delicate plants, outside water pipes, or whatever).

Comment: Yes.  Where freezing is a general reference to temperature and not the formation of ice.  I don't often think of 30F as freezing.

Comment: You need much more roundabout phrasing to say anything more detailed / accurate than just ***freezing = very cold***. Most *people* in Holland probably live in urban areas, where there's excess heat *and* crud on the pavements / salt on the roads, so you might not see any ice even if the actual temperature was well below 0 °C. Come to that, snow is "frozen water", and it can often snow when the ground temperature is well above freezing (it just melts instead of "settling"). Mostly in such contexts, ***freezing*** is a rather "imprecise" term.

Comment: (Witness all the people who've ever said ***I'm freezing**!* If they were ***literally*** freezing, they wouldn't be able to *speak*, and couldn't possibly *survive* the experience! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica I've been told that "it's freezing" means it is cold and therefore not appropriate.

Comment: Not appropriate for *what?* Anglophones simply don't think of "freezing" the same way as "raining" or "snowing", so I think the bottom line here is you're looking for a word to put into a construction that people just don't use much anyway. Being below zero isn't really something the weather "does", So *It's freezing* is a completely different construction to *It's raining* or *It's snowing*, and there is no value for *It's xxxing* that would suit the latter context with the sense of *being sufficiently cold that any exposed water would freeze*,

Comment: @ FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica how would you express the fact that the temperature dropped below freezing point last night?

Comment: @anouk I would express it exactly as you have.  *The temperature dropped below freezing last night*.  That will be understood and is a very common way to express it.  Keep it mind that is not the same as saying *It was freezing last night*, which means it was very cold, without consideration of the freezing point of water.  As stated, it's just not that common to talk about the temperature dropping below freezing.  It has very little impact on day to day life.

Comment: @EllieK: Of course, something we often say in this context is ***There was a [hard] frost last night*** (nearly always with the indefinite article). But we'd rarely say ***There was rain last night*** (and there's almost *never* an article there), because that one  is invariably expressed as ***It rained last night***. That's the point I'm trying to get across here - there's no natural usage of the general form ***It xxxxed last night*** for "freeze" the way there is for "rain, snow, hail".

Comment: I wanted to follow up here because I have new information.  With the recent cold snap my local area experienced three weeks of temperatures below 0C, which is quite rare.  This resulted in many lakes and streams being covered in enough ice that snowmobilers and ice-fishers could do those things.  People actually began to refer to exactly what the OP asked.  This is what they said, *The lakes are all frozen over because it has been **below freezing** for three weeks.*  Now I know.